# Django Prefetch and prefetch_related not working for reverse foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, orm, django-templates

I have the following models for which despite using Prefetch and prefetch_related, a sql is fired. I am trying to get the address of any of the ClientBranchDetails corresponding to the despatch_branch of the Folio model.

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
class ClientBranch(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ClientBranchDetails(models.Model):
    client_branch = models.ForeignKey('ClientBranch', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='all_client_branch_details')
    sap_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Folio(models.Model):
    folio_nbr = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    client_branch = models.ForeignKey('ClientBranch', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_branch')
    despatch_branch = models.ForeignKey('ClientBranch', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='despatch_branch')
```

The code is as follows

```
client_branch_and_details=ClientBranch.objects.prefetch_related('all_client_branch_details')
folios=Folio.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('despatch_branch', queryset=client_branch_and_details, to_attr='branch_details'))
f=folios[0]
f.despatch_branch.id
f.branch_details
```

The 3rd line above fires a SQL query as expected but so does the 4th and 5th line and this is not what I was expecting.

Comment: If you need the id of `despatch_branch`, use `f.despatch_branch_id` instead to avoid the query on the 4th line. The 5th line is firing an sql is expected. That's the 2nd query prefetch is using to get all related `despatch_branch`